# Batch file for assigning parts of a filename into a variable

Tags: batch-file

My working directory is Master and it contains a batch file and a Data folder. In my data folder, I have multiple csv files in the following format XX_year-month or i.e., XX_2019-01. I would like to write a batch file on how to extract the year and month and assign a variable to it. So far this is how I got:

```
for /r %%f in (Data/*.csv) do (
  echo here's a file %%f
  set year = %%f
  set month = %%f
)
```

Comment: The `FOR` variable can only be a single character.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?` to read the help.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, I'm new to this language.

Comment: do it with another `for /f` loop with proper tokens and delims (`for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=_-" %%a in ("%%~nf") do set "year=%%a" & set "month=%%b"